# Android: Pass Strings into asyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm currently trying to implement an example of threading into my project where I want to pass in a username and password input by the user into the thread so it can be detected if an account exists or not, but I'm having difficulties correctly implementing it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is one of the errors I am receiving.

> Class 'checkPassword2' must be declared abstract or implement abstract method >'doInBackground(Params...) in 'AsyncTask'

package com.example.liam.ca3;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.os.AsyncTask;


public class LoginScreen extends Activity {

    private final static String TAG = "Sleep";

    private static final String defName = "admin";
    private static final String defPassword = "admin1";
    private ProgressBar mProgressBar;



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.loginscreen);

        mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);


        final EditText uname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username_edittext);
        final EditText passwd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password_edittext);

        final Button loginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                new checkPassword2().execute(uname, passwd);


                if (checkPassword(uname.getText(), passwd.getText())) {
                    Log.i("8", "accepted password");
                    // Create an explicit Intent for starting the HelloAndroid Activity
                    Intent startApp = new Intent(LoginScreen.this,
                            MainActivity.class);

                    // Use the Intent to start the HelloAndroid Activity
                    startActivity(startApp);

                } else {
                    Log.i("8", "failed password");
                    uname.setText("");
                    passwd.setText("");
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private boolean checkPassword(Editable uname, Editable passwd) {

        Log.i("2", uname.toString());
        Log.i("2", passwd.toString());

        if(uname.toString().equalsIgnoreCase(defName) && passwd.toString().equalsIgnoreCase(defPassword))
        {
            Log.i("8", "this should work");
            return true;
        }
        Log.i("8", "this shouldn't work");
        return false;
    }

    private class checkPassword2 extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, String> {
        protected int doInBackground(String... values) {
            int result = 0;

            String nameTry = values[0];
            String passTry = values[1];

            if(nameTry.equalsIgnoreCase(defName) && passTry.equalsIgnoreCase(defPassword))
            {
                Log.i("8", "this should work");
                result = 1;
            }
            else {
                Log.i("8", "this shouldn't work");
                result = 2;
            }

            for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
                sleep();
                publishProgress(i * 10);
            }
            return result;
        }

        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
            mProgressBar.setProgress(progress[0]);
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.INVISIBLE);
        }

        private void sleep() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Your params are in the wrong order. `doInBackground()` gets the first param in the class definition. Also, `onPostExecute()` should except an `Integer` not a `Long` with the way you have it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

When you extend AsyncTask, you need to specify three generics:

- Params is the type of the parameters passed to doInBackground()
- Progress is the type of the parameters passed to onProgressUpdate() and publishProgress()
- Result is the type of the parameters passed to onCancelled() and onPostExecute(), and is the return type of doInBackground()

In your code, there is a mismatch between the declared generic types and the type of the parameters. Your generics are "Integer, Integer, String":

- Params = Integer
- Progress = Integer
- Result = String

Now let's look at your code...

```
doInBackground(String... values)
```

Misatch: it expects Integer parameters, you specify String parameters. But you do return an Integer.

```
onPostExecute(Long result)
```

Mismatch: it expects Integer parameters, you specify Long parameters.

Make sure the types in the methods respect those specified in the generics clause and everything should be fine.

Comment: Thanks a ton, I actually looked at the documentation beforehand but ended up confusing myself in the process, but the way you explain it really helped out. I do have one more problem however in that I'm unsure how to pass in my user defined name and password into the thread. `new checkPassword2().execute(uname, passwd);`

Comment: First, you must change the type of the first generic (Params) to String. Second, in the `doInBackground(String... values)` method, you should first check that the length of `values` is 2 (`values.length == 2`) and then the username is `values[0]` and the password is `values[1]`.

Comment: I had the same general idea implemented myself in my code, but it's the initial call to the thread that's proving to be difficult. It states that: `Cannot resolve method 'execute(android.widget.EditText, android.widget.EditText)'`

Comment: You're passing an EditText object to the method. Try this: `doInBackground(uname.getText().toString(), passwd.getText().toString())`.

Comment: Hmm, that only seemed to cause more issues than it fixed - however I figured it out myself by simple converting the EditText objects into strings before passing them in. Thanks for all the help, guy!